# Differential Equations: Non autonomous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I found this question in the back of my DE book. I can't think of anything that applies.

Give an example of a nonautonomous DE for which there is a solution $y$ with $y(t) \to q$ as $t \to \infty$, but $q$ is not an equilibrium point. You do not need to think beyond a first order linear homogeneous equation $y'(t)=a(t)y$.

Comment: What do you mean by "EP"?

Comment: equilibrium point

Comment: The solution to $y'=\frac{y}{(t+1)^2}$ is $y(t)=y_0 e^{1-(t+1)^{-1}}\to ey_0$ as $t\to\infty$. This equation has the equilibrium point $y\equiv0$, which is not $ey_0$.